# Differentiate between abbreviation and simply capitalised words?

Tags: nlp, classification

I am new to NLP and I have to solve an exercise for my NLP class. Basically, I receive a raw-text containing abbreviations like (CRF, ABC, etc) and also other types of capitalised words (FOOD, HOUSE) and I have to classify them.

I don't know where to start, can you point me to some algorithms? Stochastic approaches that can help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary of "regular" English words (spelling dict's on Linux, WordNet, etc.) and check if the word is in there. Second, use a part-of-speech tagger. If the word is not a noun, it is unlikely to be an acronym. Finally, check existing software, e.g. Acronym Finder, and papers (on Google Scholar, search for "acronym detection").

Answer (score 0):

Agree with fnl. Using a part-of-speech which contains common english words and train your text dataset. It will automatically mark 'None','Verb', and 'Abbreviation'. There are many kinds of pos and it would be better if you can choose one which has a closer area to your text data. 
For example, http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/TweetNLP/ provides a pos for tweets.

Comment: I agree that the idea of using a pos tagger would help if i would have only abbreviations and nouns, but what if I have other cases of false-abbreviations like roman letters (I, V, VI) or single letters from the alphabet (hepatitis A, B or C). Would the pos tagger be enough to distinguish between those cases too?